# Rounded corner issue with GIF image in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, gif

I am new for react native and i am showing a list of GIF images in list view and i what image corner rounded i try to do this with normal images and it's working but with GIF image it's not working i don't now why.

I use below style and code for make corner rounded.

```
  <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  horizontal= { true }
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
  renderRow={(rowData) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => this.stickerSelected(rowData)}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={this.props.images[rowData].src}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }}
  />



list: {
justifyContent: 'center',
flexDirection: 'column',
backgroundColor: '#FFFDEB',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
paddingLeft: 6,
paddingRight: 6


},
  item: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#EAD62F',
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 3,
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
  },
  image: {
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 10,
  }
```

and tried to add below property in image and item style for resolve overlapping issue but corner still in square shape.

```
 overflow: 'hidden',
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to set overlayColor style. It described here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#style

`image: {
  width: 75,
  height: 75,
  borderRadius: 10,
  overlayColor: 'white',
}`

Comment: Is there any other way? because my gif is on top of a multi colored pattern background. So I can't give it a solid overlayColor.

Comment: New Link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props#overlaycolor-android

Answer (score 2):

```
<View style={styles.imgBorder}>
  <Image source={require('../../assets/images/giphy2.gif')}
                style={styles.profilePicture} />
</View>

profilePicture: {
    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '20%',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'purple',
},
imgBorder: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 300,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '20%',
}
```

You can wrap GIF with View container. After than usual height and width configurations with overFlow: 'Hidden' your problem will be fixed.