# Android GIF borderRadius without overlayColor

Tags: android, react-native

All of my gifs are on non-solid backgrounds. The only way to get GIFs to respect borderRadius right now is to use a hack called overlayColor per:

- [Rounded corner issue with GIF image in react native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463147/rounded-corner-issue-with-gif-image-in-react-native-android/41715524)
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11363

Does anyone have any other solution? `overlayColor` is not a solution for my use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to wrap the Image in a View and have both the Image and the View with the same borderRadius.
EDIT: originally I said the image needed to have an overlayColor but it looks like it has no effect (which makes sense). Added code example that I'm using:

```html
<View style={{ width: 80, height: 80, borderRadius: 40, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
     <Image
         source={image}
         resizeMode='cover'
         style={{
            borderRadius: 40,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            width: 80,
            height: 80
         }} />
</View>
```

Comment: Wow very interesting, thanks for sharing, could you share some code please?

Comment: @Noitidart added the code and edited my answer for more clarity!